# Attempting to get GUI to cycle through data starting back at the beginning

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to get the GUI to fully cycle through
but I run into an error after third next button click array element[2]. What I need to do is have the whole thing cycle through when clicking the next button. once it gets to the last iteration of the array will need to go back to the beginning. The thing also is the array is sorted alphabetically to begin with so it would need to start with titles [3] once it has cycled through. Thanks for all the help

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton next;
    JButton previous;
    JButton first;
    JButton last;

    private JLabel itmNum = new JLabel("Item Number: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField itemNumber;
    private JLabel proNm = new JLabel ("Product Name: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField prodName;
    private JLabel yr = new JLabel("Year Made: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField year;
    private JLabel unNum = new JLabel("Unit Number: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField unitNumber;
    private JLabel prodPrice = new JLabel("Product Price: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField price;
    private JLabel restkFee = new JLabel("Restocking Fee", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField rsFee;
    private JLabel prodInValue = new JLabel("Product Inventory Value", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField prodValue;
    private JLabel totalValue = new JLabel("Total Value of All Products", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    private JTextField tValue;
    private double toValue;
    Movies[] titles = new Movies[9];
    int nb = 0;

    public GUI() 
    {

        super ("Inventory Program Part 5");
        setSize(800,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLookAndFeel();




        first = new JButton("First");
        previous = new JButton("Previous");
        next = new JButton("Next");
        last = new JButton("Last");
        first.addActionListener(this);
        previous.addActionListener(this);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        last.addActionListener(this);




        //Movies[] titles = new Movies[9];

        titles [0] = new Movies(10001, "King Arthur", 25 , 9.99, 2004, .05);

        titles [1] = new Movies(10002,"Tron", 25, 7.99, 1982, .05);

        titles [2] = new Movies(10003, "Tron: Legacy",25,24.99,2010,.05);

        titles [3] = new Movies(10004,"Braveheart", 25,2.50,1995,.05);

        titles [4] = new Movies(10005,"Gladiator",25,2.50,2000,.05);

        titles [5] = new Movies(10006,"CaddyShack SE",25,19.99,1980,.05);

        titles [6] = new Movies (10007,"Hackers",25,12.50,1995,.05);

        titles [7] = new Movies (10008,"Die Hard Trilogy",25,19.99,1988,.05);

        titles [8] = new Movies (10009,"Terminator",25,4.99,1984,.05);

        Arrays.sort (titles, DVD.prodNameComparator);






                        itemNumber = new JTextField(Double.toString(titles[3].getitemNum()));
                        prodName = new JTextField(titles[3].getprodName());
                        year= new JTextField(Integer.toString(titles[3].getYear()));
                        unitNumber= new JTextField(Integer.toString(titles[3].getunitNum()));
                        price= new JTextField(Float.toString(titles[3].getprice()));
                        rsFee= new JTextField(Double.toString(titles[3].getRestkFee()));
                        prodValue= new JTextField(Double.toString(titles[3].getprodValue()));
                        tValue= new JTextField("2636");
                        nb=0;
                        next.addActionListener(this);



        setLayout(new GridLayout(8,4));
        add(itmNum);
        add(itemNumber);
        add(proNm);
        add(prodName);
        add(yr);
        add(year);
        add(unNum);
        add(unitNumber);
        add(prodPrice);
        add(price);
        add(restkFee);
        add(rsFee);
        add(prodInValue);
        add(prodValue);
        add(totalValue);
        add(tValue);
        add(first);
        add(previous);
        add(next);
        add(last);
        setLookAndFeel();
        setVisible(true);


    }



    public void updateFields()
    {
        nb++;
        itemNumber.setText(Double.toString(titles[nb].getitemNum()));
        prodName.setText(titles[nb].getprodName());
        year.setText(Integer.toString(titles[nb].getYear()));
        unitNumber.setText(Integer.toString(titles[nb].getunitNum()));
        price.setText(Double.toString(titles[nb].getprice()));
        rsFee.setText(Double.toString(titles[nb].getRestkFee()));
        prodValue.setText(Double.toString(titles[nb].getprodValue()));

    }




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source == next) 
        {
            if (titles[nb]== titles[8])
            {
                titles[nb] = titles[0];
            }
            else {
                nb++;
            }
            updateFields();
        }

    }

    private void setLookAndFeel()
    {
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("couln't use the system"+ "look and feel: " + e);
            }

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are advancing so quickly through the records is that you have added your `ActionListener` to your `next` `JButton` *twice*:

```
next.addActionListener(this);
```

This, in turn, increments your record index (`nb`) in the `ActionListener` *as well* as in your `updateFields` method. Remove this increment from *one* of these locations.

Also, when you check if you've reached the last title, you never reset your record index `nb`. You could do:

```
if (titles[nb] == titles[8]) {
   nb = 0;
   ...
```

Comment: I saw that and removed it however once I hit titles[2] the program crashes, the other thing I found that was interesting is that is should start on titles[3] but instead it starts on titles[4] so I started it back on element 0 and the first to display is titles[3] which is should because it is sorted in alphabetical order but it skips other elements

Comment: I see what you are saying and thank you for your help. Now I have noticed when I try to add the next button i get Actionperformed problems.